# conditionally execute macro function

Tags: sas

I want to conditionally execute macro function dependent on existence of table

Data

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 5;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Table I want to condition on

```
data counttbl;
    infile datalines delimiter='::'; 
    format variable $char400. condition $char400.;
    input variable $ condition $;
    datalines;
runcount::i>1
;
run;
```

Some tests to show that I can condition on `counttbl` existence (works as expected)

```
data _null_;
    call execute("data want;");
    call execute("set have;");
    if exist("work.counttbl") then
        call execute("tmp = 1;");
    call execute('run;');
stop;
run;
```

The above creates column `tmp = 1`

```
proc delete data=work.counttbl;
run;

data _null_;
    call execute("data want;");
    call execute("set have;");
    if exist("work.counttbl") then
        call execute("tmp = 1;");
    call execute('run;');
stop;
run;
```

After deleting the table, the above does not create the column `tmp`

Macro function to execute

```
%macro apply_change();
    call execute('if _n_ eq 1 then do;');
    do until (eof);
        set counttbl (keep=variable) end=eof;
        call execute(strip(variable) || ' = 0;');
    end;
    call execute('end;');
    call missing(eof);
    do until (eof);
        set counttbl end=eof;
        call execute(strip(variable) || ' + (' || strip(condition) || ');');
    end;
    call missing(eof);
%mend apply_change;
```

Works fine when `counttbl` exists

```
data _null_;
    call execute("data want;");
    call execute("set have;");
    if exist("work.counttbl") then
        %apply_change()
    call execute('run;');
stop;
run;
```

Throws error when `counttbl` is deleted - I want it to simply skip executing the macro function

```
proc delete data=work.counttbl;
run;

data _null_;
    call execute("data want;");
    call execute("set have;");
    if exist("work.counttbl") then
        %apply_change()
    call execute('run;');
stop;
run;

ERROR: File WORK.COUNTTBL.DATA does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It really looks like your solution is way too complex for the problem, but I am not sure what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your post - when `counttbl` does not exist, the last block of code throws the error `File WORK.COUNTTBL.DATA does not exist`. I want it to simply ignore the macro function when `counttbl` does not exist.

Comment: When `counttbl` exists, the macro runs fine - the issue is not running the macro per se, it's more about suppressing the macro when `counttbl` does not exist

Comment: You don't want to suppress the macro per se, but the code that the macro generates.  Conditional generation of code is one of the main reasons for creating a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem area is

```
if exist("work.counttbl") then
    %apply_change()
```

Macro is processed, and generates source code, prior to the SAS system implicitly compiling the data step and running it.

I would not recommend pursuing this avenue because it mixes scopes (macro/data step)

If you persist, there are a couple of tips

- place all the code generation in a macro
- place the existential check in the macro, and do NOT codegen source that has a `SET counttbl` when not present

For example:

```
%macro apply_change();
    %if not %sysfunc(EXISTS(WORK.COUNTTBL)) %then %return; 

    %* This code gen only done when COUNTTBL present;
    call execute('if _n_ eq 1 then do;');
    do until (eof);
        set counttbl (keep=variable) end=eof;
        call execute(strip(variable) || ' = 0;');
    end;
    call execute('end;');
    call missing(eof);
    do until (eof);
        set counttbl end=eof;
        call execute(strip(variable) || ' + (' || strip(condition) || ');');
    end;
    call missing(eof);
%mend apply_change;
```

Replace

```
if exist("work.counttbl") then %apply_change()
```

With

```
%apply_change()
```

Comment: Thanks, the other answers touched on the same problems you also pointed out, but this is the simplest fix.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a test at run time to prevent SAS from compiling some lines of code in the same data step.  Instead you need to use macro logic to not generate the lines of code.

It looks like you want to use the dataset to generate a series of variables that count how many times a condition is met.  I find that it is much easier to debug if that type of data driven code generation is done by writing the code to a file. Then you can stop after generating the file and look at the generated code and make sure your code generation step is working properly.

It looks like you want the new dataset generated whether or not the file with the list of VARIABLE/CONDITION pairs exists or not. So just hard code that part of the data step and only conditionally generate the part that calculates the new variables. Since you are generating sum statements there is not need for the IF _N_=1 block to set the initial values to zero.  SAS will automatically set them to zero and retain them. (Assuming that HAVE doesn't already have variables with those names, in which the sum statement won't work right either.)

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  file code ;
%if %sysfunc(exist(&dsname)) %then %do;
  set &dsname end=eof;
  put '  ' variable '+ ( ' condition ');' ;
%end ;
run;
```

So either the temp file CODE is empty or it has code like:

```
VAR1 + ( dx='123' );
VAR2 + ( sex='M' );
```

Then to make your dataset just run this step with a `%INCLUDE` to add in the conditionally generated code.

```
data want;
  set have;
%include code /source2;
run;
```

If you are using an old version of SAS you will need to wrap that `%IF` statement into a macro.  But the newest releases of SAS allow that type of simple %IF/%THEN/%DO/%END construct in open code.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
if exist("work.counttbl") then
```

will only apply to the first line of your macro

```
 call execute('if _n_ eq 1 then do;');
```

This is because the macro is evaluated before the datastep is executed. So sas will simple paste the macro content to the location of the macro invocation.
But even when it would apply to the whole macro it will not work.
Take for example the following code:

```
data x;
  if 0 then do;
    set y;
  end;
  set z;
run;
```

Her y and z has to exist. However no observation will be read from y only structure is taken.